# This Python code to get the current file path will work on Linux?

Tags: python, linux, windows, path

Sorry if it's a stupid question, I don't know anything about Linux and I've had problems with paths in Linux, will this Python code I made in Windows work in Linux?

Code:

```
File_Path = str(Path(__file__).parent.absolute())
User_Dir = File_Path + '/data'
```

If you can explain more about the compatibility of Python codes from Windows to Linux I would appreciate it.

Comment: Why don't you try and see?

Comment: I'm waiting for someone to explain me more about Python code compatibility from Windows to Linux, as I don't understand Linux!

Comment: Yes it will work

Answer (score 0):

For me, it will work, but I have 2 questions :

- Why don't you use Path Library more ? Like this :

> ```
> File_Path = Path(__file__).parent.absolute()
> User_Dir = File_Path.join('data')
> ```

- and user_dir we are agree it's the directory "data" next to your sourcefile ?

Comment: I didn't remember that I could use File_Path.join('data'), thanks, /data will be a folder inside the current folder, the /data folder will be created when I run a file inside the current folder.

Comment: You can get the current folder with "Path()", so you won't have to copy your source file. It's as you want :)